# Pandas and CSV Libraries CSV Manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am building a simple app.

I want some values in my CSV to be updated every 15 minutes. I want
this part of my app to run in the background to prevent blocking the interface.

I couldn't get it to work the way I want to.

My code:

```
# I'm using the pandas, sched and time imports here:

#INTERFACE
@app.route("/")
def home():
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    s.enter(15, 1, timer)
    s.run()
    return render_template("index.html")

#TIMER
def timer():
  timer = 0
  csv_file='C:\Python27\Walmart\sheet.csv'
  print("UPDATING")
  data_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
  print("READ")
  for i, row in data_df.iterrows() :
      sku = data_df.iloc[i]['Walmart SKU']
      print (sku)
      if sku is '':
        break
      else:
        update(sku)
        print("Item Updated")
  print("UPDATECOMPLETE")
  home()

#UPDATE
def update(sku):

     lookup=str(sku)
     lookup = lookup.replace('.0', '')
     product = wapy.product_lookup(lookup)
     ts = time.time()

     st = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')
     print (product.name)

     if product.available_online is 'TRUE':
        instock = 'yes'
     else:
        instock ='no'

     quote_page = product.product_url
     page = urlopen(quote_page)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
     sold_box = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'font-bold prod-SoldShipByMsg'})
     sold = sold_box.text.strip()
     left_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'prod-ProductOffer-urgencyMsg'})
     left = left_box.text.strip()

     if left is '':
       stock=product.stock
     else:
       stock=left

     # fields=[lookup + ',' + '$'+str(product.sale_price) + ',' + instock + ',' + stock + ',' + str(sold) + ',' + st + ',' + '$'+str(product.msrp)]
     pathto_csv = 'C:\Python27\Walmart\sheet.csv'
     data_df = pd.read_csv(pathto_csv)
     print("CSV READ")

     data_df.set_value([lookup], ['Price'], '$'+str(product.sale_price))
     data_df.set_value([lookup], ['In Stock'], instock )
     data_df.set_value([lookup], ['Quantity'], stock)
     data_df.set_value([lookup], ['Last Update'], str(sold))
     data_df.set_value([lookup], ['Min Price'], '$'+str(product.msrp))

     data_df.to_csv(pathto_csv)

     with open(r'sheet.csv', 'a') as f:
         writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar = ' ')
         writer.writerow(fields)
     print(st)
     print("UPDATED! 15 Minutes Have Passed!")
```

**I have two problems:**

**1. On replacing the value on my update I'm getting this error:**

```
KeyError: "['879091509'] not in index"
```

I thought that `[row],[column]` would let me replace the value I want for that cell, for example:

```
data_df.set_value([lookup], ['Price'], '$'+str(product.sale_price))
```

I read this as:

- on row of where my SKU or ID is represented by `['lookup']`
- replace the `['Price']` by `'$'+str(product.sale_price)`

**2. I can't get to my interface.**

- I think this is because:

  - when the time resets it runs the code again.

**Question:** How can I make this run only in background?

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

There are two issues:

1. The first argument `set_value` searches the DataFrame's index, but your DataFrame doesn't have an index.
2. You're passing lists to `set_value` but it just needs values.

To fix, first set an index:

```
data_df = data_df.set_index('Walmart SKU')
```

And remove the lists from `set_value`:

```
data_df.set_value(lookup, 'Price', '$'+str(product.sale_price))
```

**Q2**

Is not clear enough to answer. Try asking a new question with a minimum test case.